# Inputting into a file

Tags: python

Requests the user for an input based on their name, how they are feeling and what they would like to do for the day.

Once the code is run, it will ask these for these inputs and the user would of course have to enter the input in the Python IDLE.

Instead of the user entering their inputs into the Python IDLE, I would like the user to answer the questions in the text file instead. How would i do this?

```
questions = open ("questions.txt","a+")

quest1 = input("Hi what is your name?: ")
quest2 = input("How are you today?: ")
quest3 = input("What would you like to do?: ")

allQuests = quest1+","+quest2+","+quest3

questions.write(str(allQuests+("\n"))
questions.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: It seems that you're asking how to get the user to use a text editor instead of your Python interface.  Is that correct?  If so, then the problem is beyond our control, and your **python** tag is inapplicable.

Comment: No, I want the user to answer the question in a text file and not answer in python. @Prune

Comment: Please clarify: how does the user "answer the question in a text file" without using a text editor?  Please show the sequence of steps -- a script for the user experience.  The user doesn't "answer in Python"; s/he provides input to a running Python program, but is not writing in the Python language.  Perhaps you and I have a translation problem?

Comment: Or perhaps I couldn't understand your question and you didn't understand my answer, of course apologies to you. @Prune

Comment: Also possible.  The important part is to get an answer that matches your problem.

Comment: Since I couldn't find an answer to the problem, I turned the problem into a question and the answer to a result. So @Prune How would i use a text editor?

Comment: If you're writing Python source code in files, you're already using a text editor.

Comment: So I need the user to use a text editor rather than the python interface.

Comment: That's what *I* get from your problem statement.  If all you want is to have the user's responses added to the lines of the text file, and you don't want the user to use a Python program, then it seems that a text editor is the most direct way to go.

Comment: However, if you want to have any interaction as the user enters responses, then we can work on a simple Python program that will manage the updates.  That's what I'm trying to clarify.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to say. For clarification, I want an interaction between the user's responses, How do i do that?

Comment: you need to give a detailed description of how you want this interaction to work, then make a reasonable beginning at the implementation.  See "How to Ask" and "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example" (MVCE) in the intro tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an io.StringIO (or in 2.7 StringIO) object with the contents read from the text file

```
import io

answer_file = 'file name of the answer file'
f = open(answer_file)
myStringIOvar = io.StringIO(f.read())
f.close()
```

and then set

```
 sys.stdin = myStringIOvar
```

so that your calls to `input()` read from the stream coming from your text file.  The prompts will still show up (uselessly) on stdout and you will be unable to read from standard input at any later point in your program.

A better solution would be to rewrite your program to look at sys.args and see if a filename was passed on the command line.  If so call a subroutine that returns the data read from a file.  If not call a subroutine that uses `input()` to prompt the user interactively.

Another option would be for your program to first ask the user for the answer file name and if they don't provide an answer (i.e. just hit return) you ask interactively.